# syntax error in python code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

Can you tell me where the syntax error in this code is??

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)

try: 
    while True:
        if (GPIO.input(4) == 1):
            print "button pressed"
        else:
            print "he"
GPIO.cleanup()
```

it should print button pressed when the gpio pin on my raspberry pi gets power when the button on the board is pressed. but i get an error all the time i run the code in the console running raspbian. most of the errors say "invalid syntax" and than the last codeline of the script.

Comment: Post the full error you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `try` with no `except` clause. You need something like:

```
try:
    while True:
        if (GPIO.input(4) == 1):
            print "button pressed"
        else:
            print "he"
except:
    # handle exception here
    pass # if you want to ignore it
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: yeah now the syntax error is gone. great but i got this:

RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!

i tried running as root but still this error

Comment: That's a different problem and I can't help you with that one. You'll need to ask a new question.